# Unable to delete React project folder

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, delete-file, project-folder

I am trying to create react app using following command

```
npx create-react-app sales
```

unfortunately its getting stuck at some point or other while installing packages. This time it gets stuck at below package (Ref Images).

[image]

[image]

After waiting for 5, 10 mins I cancelled the installation (Ctrl+C). But strangely I am not able to delete project folder also.

I also **re-installed the node** but the problem still persists.

How do I delete the folder?

Comment: Probably, as usual, Windows OS is locking your directory with some process. Did you tried to restart your OS?

Answer (score 0):

```
rm -rf sales
```

If this doesn't work, try using `sudo` in front